# Camera data of Galaxy S3 for tracking

Tags: camera

I'm trying to make a camera tracking of a video make by my Samsung Galaxy S3 (I9300), but I can't find info about its focal length, sensor size, etc. so the scene and camera match exactly what was used when filming.

I think that maybe ok to use default settings but if some one know what need to be set for the Samsung Galaxy S3 could be very good, so things get more accurate.

Comment: Related (for other older phone/camera models): [What are the technical specs of cameras in Android devices?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4388/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?273784-Camera-Sensor-Width-%28Galaxy-S3%29) thread on Blenderartists, sensor size is 4.54 × 3.42 mm and focal length is 3.7mm, which gives a crop factor of 7.7 and a 35mm-equiv. focal length of 28.5 mm.

Be careful to check if the video is cropped in comparison to the still images, reducing the effective sensor size.